# Tentando criar um bot do discord com python

Tags: python

Olá! Eu estava programando um bot no python com o seguinte comando

```
 import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Josefino está online!')

client.run('minha token')
```

invés de aparecer "Josefino está online!" no Shell

Apareceu esse enorme código:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/JosefinoBot(agora com py)/JosefinoBot.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.run('NzMyOTg4NTY0NzE5MTQwOTE3.XxDUqA.u6db3PwcDrp2-1UQK89-g9Ukw0E')
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

O que eu faço? Eu sou um newbie em programação!

Eu agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Me parece que o programa falhou ao conectar com o servidor do Discord, mas digo isso olhando bem por alto, na real pode ser outra coisa. Se você nunca programou antes, aprender a programar criando um bot pode proporcionar uma curva de aprendizado um pouco dura. Recomendo você aprender os fundamentos da programação antes, e quando já estiver com uma noção melhor, retomar esse projeto. Existem vários materiais gratuitos de introdução a programação com Python na internet de ótima qualidade, vide o curso do professor Gustavo Guanabara no Youtube e o site Automate The Boring Stuff With Python.

Answer (score 0):

Tive esse mesmo problema, a única forma que conseguir resolver foi instalando um certificado(?) no meu computador.

Você pode baixar ele aqui: https://crt.sh/?id=2835394

O botão de download é meio escondido mas se encontra aqui: [image: onde encontrar o link de download]